# Any way to bold grand total line in a report

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I am using a bash script to generate a report for higher management and sending it through mail with the help of cronjob but my problem is that we need Grand_Total line in bold format.

I am getting results by below multiple queries:

```
mysql -H -u$DBUSER -p$DBPASS test -e "SELECT IFNULL(cust_name,'Grand_Total') AS cust_name,SUM(order_amt) AS amt FROM mytable1 GROUP BY cust_name WITH ROLLUP;" > REPORT_FILE.txt

mysql -H -u$DBUSER -p$DBPASS test -e "SELECT IFNULL(cust_name,'Grand_Total') AS cust_name,SUM(order_amt) AS amt FROM mytable2 GROUP BY cust_name WITH ROLLUP;" >> REPORT_FILE.txt

mysql -H -u$DBUSER -p$DBPASS test -e "SELECT IFNULL(cust_name,'Grand_Total') AS cust_name,SUM(order_amt) AS amt FROM mytable3 GROUP BY cust_name WITH ROLLUP;" >> REPORT_FILE.txt
```

It will generate output in html format in REPORT_FILE.txt file.

I want to Bold my "Grand_Total" line either through mysql query (if there is any way, as per me there is no way in mysql) or after exporting data in txt file with the help of any linux command.

Comment: Are you sure your commands are generating *HTML* content? It does not look likely!

Comment: Yes it is storing results in html tags...

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file in some other scripting language such as Python, Perl etc and you can parse the file and change the required columns as per required.

You may even use sed or awk to edit the sepcific columns you want to.

Comment: Yes I know it can be in linux by sed or awk but still exploring for solution...If you can help me to get command then please share.

Comment: @ZafarMalik if you would share a sample output/content of the Text file, i might be able to give you python/bash snippet that you use for getting what you want.

Comment: as the output contains html tag and when I am updating output then stack..site is removing them before upload..so let me know how can i update here...Further I tried following command: awk 'match($0,"<TD>Grand.*"){print substr($0,RSTART)}' $REPORT_FILE | sed -i 's/TD/TH/g' $REPORT_FILE but it is replacing in whole file instead of filtered data.

Comment: @ZafarMalik Give MySQL snippet is not generating any HTML, where you are adding HTML to the result of MySQL query as per shown above. You question is not very could you please update with more information.

Comment: Actually queries mentioned above are dummy but I am getting final output in a file which is attached in dpaste.de/eKNg link, now i want to bold the grand total line.....here if I can replace TD with TH in this file but only after <TD>Grand Total to end of line in all lines then I can achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution by below perl script, so first my script will generate report in mytext.txt file then this perl script will search "TD" word in each line but between `<TD>Grand Total</TD>` to end of line and after replacing it with "TH" print it to myoutput.txt file along with the lines those don't have these keyword. So finally my Grand Total line will be displayed as Bold in report.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open (INPUTFILE, "mytext.txt") or die ("Unable to find the file");
open (OUTFILE, ">myoutput.txt") or die ("Unable to find the file");
my @lines = <INPUTFILE>;
foreach my $str (@lines) {
        if (my ($matches) = $str =~ /(<TD>Grand Total<\/TD>(<TD>-?[0-9.]+<\/TD>)*)/) {
                my $orig = $matches;
                $matches =~ tr/TD/TH/ ;
                $str =~ s/$orig/$matches/;
                print OUTFILE $str;
        }else{
                print OUTFILE $str;
        }
```

### }

---

mytext.txt conent is below-

```
<br><br>Shoes Bulk Inventory Report <br><br>
<TABLE BORDER=1><TR><TH>Shoes</TH><TH>size 6</TH><TH>size 7</TH><TH>size 8</TH><TH>size 9</TH><TH>size 10</TH><TH>size 11</TH><TH>LastDay_Total</TH><TH>Today_Total</TH><TH>Quantity Change</TH><TH>% Change</TH></TR><TR><TD>Marco ferro Boot - Black - 198747</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>40</TD><TD>143</TD><TD>301</TD><TD>23</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>556</TD><TD>507</TD><TD>-49</TD><TD>-8.81</TD></TR><TR><TD>Lotto Marathon Shoes White Navy - 196553</TD><TD>2</TD><TD>410</TD><TD>105</TD><TD>26</TD><TD>152</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>705</TD><TD>695</TD><TD>-10</TD><TD>-1.42</TD></TR><TR><TD>LOTTO MAGIC SHOES - Blue - 196552</TD><TD>51</TD><TD>224</TD><TD>644</TD><TD>1925</TD><TD>698</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>3672</TD><TD>3542</TD><TD>-130</TD><TD>-3.54</TD></TR><TR><TD>Lancer LCR Footwear JJ Air White Navy - 221068</TD><TD>211</TD><TD>383</TD><TD>206</TD><TD>400</TD><TD>141</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>7</TD><TD>1341</TD><TD>1334</TD><TD>19057.14</TD></TR><TR><TD>Columbus Shoes - Green - 202033</TD><TD>65</TD><TD>190</TD><TD>134</TD><TD>128</TD><TD>532</TD><TD>640</TD><TD>2068</TD><TD>1689</TD><TD>-379</TD><TD>-18.33</TD></TR><TR><TD>Columbus Race2 White Blue Sports Shoe - 217145</TD><TD>94</TD><TD>87</TD><TD>32</TD><TD>80</TD><TD>108</TD><TD>132</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>533</TD><TD>533</TD><TD>100.00</TD></TR><TR><TD>Columbus Footwear Tab105 White Royal Blue - 215963</TD><TD>1</TD><TD>4</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>1</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>10</TD><TD>27</TD><TD>16</TD><TD>-11</TD><TD>-40.74</TD></TR><TR><TD>Stylish Biker Shoe - 198909</TD><TD>3</TD><TD>89</TD><TD>53</TD><TD>20</TD><TD>105</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>272</TD><TD>270</TD><TD>-2</TD><TD>-0.74</TD></TR><TR><TD>Rocio Sports shoe Blue White - 198456</TD><TD>10</TD><TD>2</TD><TD>164</TD><TD>203</TD><TD>107</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>487</TD><TD>486</TD><TD>-1</TD><TD>-0.21</TD></TR><TR><TD>Rocio Sports Shoe  White Blue - 198457</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>9</TD><TD>66</TD><TD>9</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>108</TD><TD>84</TD><TD>-24</TD><TD>-22.22</TD></TR><TR><TD>Rocio Formal Shoes  - 38087</TD><TD>67</TD><TD>183</TD><TD>206</TD><TD>98</TD><TD>54</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>656</TD><TD>608</TD><TD>-48</TD><TD>-7.32</TD></TR><TR><TD>MARCO FERRO TAN SHOES - 60894</TD><TD>334</TD><TD>6</TD><TD>6</TD><TD>164</TD><TD>268</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>784</TD><TD>778</TD><TD>-6</TD><TD>-0.77</TD></TR><TR><TD>Marco Ferro Olive Shoes - Olive - 195566</TD><TD>256</TD><TD>56</TD><TD>856</TD><TD>999</TD><TD>591</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>2814</TD><TD>2758</TD><TD>-56</TD><TD>-1.99</TD></TR><TR><TD>Marco ferro Boot - Tan - 197672</TD><TD>136</TD><TD>13</TD><TD>5</TD><TD>313</TD><TD>100</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>594</TD><TD>567</TD><TD>-27</TD><TD>-4.55</TD></TR><TR><TD>Columbus Shoes - 214619</TD><TD>7</TD><TD>90</TD><TD>82</TD><TD>30</TD><TD>87</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>283</TD><TD>296</TD><TD>13</TD><TD>4.59</TD></TR><TR><TD>Columbus Shoes - Blue - 202034</TD><TD>18</TD><TD>71</TD><TD>57</TD><TD>42</TD><TD>69</TD><TD>14</TD><TD>307</TD><TD>271</TD><TD>-36</TD><TD>-11.73</TD></TR><TR><TD>Columbus Shoes - Red - 202035</TD><TD>27</TD><TD>50</TD><TD>68</TD><TD>45</TD><TD>26</TD><TD>6</TD><TD>229</TD><TD>222</TD><TD>-7</TD><TD>-3.06</TD></TR><TR><TD>Columbus Shoes - Tab - White/Red/Black - 214618</TD><TD>33</TD><TD>145</TD><TD>86</TD><TD>73</TD><TD>88</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>420</TD><TD>425</TD><TD>5</TD><TD>1.19</TD></TR><TR><TD>Columbus Shoes - Tab White Blue - 214617</TD><TD>54</TD><TD>156</TD><TD>43</TD><TD>47</TD><TD>70</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>372</TD><TD>370</TD><TD>-2</TD><TD>-0.54</TD></TR><TR><TD>Lotto Magic Shoes - 129726</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>4</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>8</TD><TD>1</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>13</TD><TD>13</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0.00</TD></TR><TR><TD>Grand Total</TD><TD>1369</TD><TD>2203</TD><TD>2899</TD><TD>4969</TD><TD>3229</TD><TD>802</TD><TD>14374</TD><TD>15471</TD><TD>1097</TD><TD>7.63</TD></TR></TABLE>
<br><br>Small Shoes Bulk Inventory Report <br><br>
<TABLE BORDER=1><TR><TH>Shoes</TH><TH>size 4</TH><TH>size 5</TH><TH>size 6</TH><TH>size 7</TH><TH>LastDay_Total</TH><TH>Today_Total</TH><TH>Quantity Change</TH><TH>% Change</TH></TR><TR><TD>Lotto Diva Women White Pink - 203979</TD><TD>581</TD><TD>1214</TD><TD>1067</TD><TD>475</TD><TD>3341</TD><TD>3337</TD><TD>-4</TD><TD>-0.12</TD></TR><TR><TD>Grand Total</TD><TD>581</TD><TD>1214</TD><TD>1067</TD><TD>475</TD><TD>3341</TD><TD>3337</TD><TD>-4</TD><TD>-0.12</TD></TR></TABLE>
<br><br>Apparel Bulk Inventory Report<br><br>
<TABLE BORDER=1><TR><TH>Apparel</TH><TH>Size - S</TH><TH>Size - M</TH><TH>Size - L</TH><TH>Size - XL</TH><TH>Size - XXL</TH><TH>LastDay_Total</TH><TH>Today_Total</TH><TH>Quantity Change</TH><TH>% Change</TH></TR><TR><TD>Lotto Tracksuit - 199346</TD><TD>895</TD><TD>2765</TD><TD>2763</TD><TD>1646</TD><TD>778</TD><TD>8849</TD><TD>8847</TD><TD>-2</TD><TD>-0.02</TD></TR><TR><TD>Rocio Black Bomber Jacket - 201734</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>77</TD><TD>268</TD><TD>216</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>562</TD><TD>561</TD><TD>-1</TD><TD>-0.18</TD></TR><TR><TD>Rocio Black Full Sleeve Jacket with Fur Lining - 202674</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>32</TD><TD>3</TD><TD>30</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>65</TD><TD>65</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0.00</TD></TR><TR><TD>Rocio Blue Bomber Jacket - 201735</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>117</TD><TD>324</TD><TD>313</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>754</TD><TD>754</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0.00</TD></TR><TR><TD>Rocio Mens Black Tracksuit with Blue Piping - 199529</TD><TD>426</TD><TD>1301</TD><TD>1300</TD><TD>683</TD><TD>350</TD><TD>4060</TD><TD>4060</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0.00</TD></TR><TR><TD>Rocio Mens Black Tracksuit with Red Piping - 199530</TD><TD>458</TD><TD>1226</TD><TD>1330</TD><TD>739</TD><TD>332</TD><TD>4085</TD><TD>4085</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0.00</TD></TR><TR><TD>Grand Total</TD><TD>1779</TD><TD>5518</TD><TD>5988</TD><TD>3627</TD><TD>1460</TD><TD>18375</TD><TD>18372</TD><TD>-3</TD><TD>-0.02</TD></TR></TABLE>
```

myoutput.txt content after replacing TD to TH:

```
<br><br>Shoes Bulk Inventory Report <br><br>
<TABLE BORDER=1><TR><TH>Shoes</TH><TH>size 6</TH><TH>size 7</TH><TH>size 8</TH><TH>size 9</TH><TH>size 10</TH><TH>size 11</TH><TH>LastDay_Total</TH><TH>Today_Total</TH><TH>Quantity Change</TH><TH>% Change</TH></TR><TR><TD>Marco ferro Boot - Black - 198747</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>40</TD><TD>143</TD><TD>301</TD><TD>23</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>556</TD><TD>507</TD><TD>-49</TD><TD>-8.81</TD></TR><TR><TD>Lotto Marathon Shoes White Navy - 196553</TD><TD>2</TD><TD>410</TD><TD>105</TD><TD>26</TD><TD>152</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>705</TD><TD>695</TD><TD>-10</TD><TD>-1.42</TD></TR><TR><TD>LOTTO MAGIC SHOES - Blue - 196552</TD><TD>51</TD><TD>224</TD><TD>644</TD><TD>1925</TD><TD>698</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>3672</TD><TD>3542</TD><TD>-130</TD><TD>-3.54</TD></TR><TR><TD>Lancer LCR Footwear JJ Air White Navy - 221068</TD><TD>211</TD><TD>383</TD><TD>206</TD><TD>400</TD><TD>141</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>7</TD><TD>1341</TD><TD>1334</TD><TD>19057.14</TD></TR><TR><TD>Columbus Shoes - Green - 202033</TD><TD>65</TD><TD>190</TD><TD>134</TD><TD>128</TD><TD>532</TD><TD>640</TD><TD>2068</TD><TD>1689</TD><TD>-379</TD><TD>-18.33</TD></TR><TR><TD>Columbus Race2 White Blue Sports Shoe - 217145</TD><TD>94</TD><TD>87</TD><TD>32</TD><TD>80</TD><TD>108</TD><TD>132</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>533</TD><TD>533</TD><TD>100.00</TD></TR><TR><TD>Columbus Footwear Tab105 White Royal Blue - 215963</TD><TD>1</TD><TD>4</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>1</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>10</TD><TD>27</TD><TD>16</TD><TD>-11</TD><TD>-40.74</TD></TR><TR><TD>Stylish Biker Shoe - 198909</TD><TD>3</TD><TD>89</TD><TD>53</TD><TD>20</TD><TD>105</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>272</TD><TD>270</TD><TD>-2</TD><TD>-0.74</TD></TR><TR><TD>Rocio Sports shoe Blue White - 198456</TD><TD>10</TD><TD>2</TD><TD>164</TD><TD>203</TD><TD>107</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>487</TD><TD>486</TD><TD>-1</TD><TD>-0.21</TD></TR><TR><TD>Rocio Sports Shoe  White Blue - 198457</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>9</TD><TD>66</TD><TD>9</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>108</TD><TD>84</TD><TD>-24</TD><TD>-22.22</TD></TR><TR><TD>Rocio Formal Shoes  - 38087</TD><TD>67</TD><TD>183</TD><TD>206</TD><TD>98</TD><TD>54</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>656</TD><TD>608</TD><TD>-48</TD><TD>-7.32</TD></TR><TR><TD>MARCO FERRO TAN SHOES - 60894</TD><TD>334</TD><TD>6</TD><TD>6</TD><TD>164</TD><TD>268</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>784</TD><TD>778</TD><TD>-6</TD><TD>-0.77</TD></TR><TR><TD>Marco Ferro Olive Shoes - Olive - 195566</TD><TD>256</TD><TD>56</TD><TD>856</TD><TD>999</TD><TD>591</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>2814</TD><TD>2758</TD><TD>-56</TD><TD>-1.99</TD></TR><TR><TD>Marco ferro Boot - Tan - 197672</TD><TD>136</TD><TD>13</TD><TD>5</TD><TD>313</TD><TD>100</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>594</TD><TD>567</TD><TD>-27</TD><TD>-4.55</TD></TR><TR><TD>Columbus Shoes - 214619</TD><TD>7</TD><TD>90</TD><TD>82</TD><TD>30</TD><TD>87</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>283</TD><TD>296</TD><TD>13</TD><TD>4.59</TD></TR><TR><TD>Columbus Shoes - Blue - 202034</TD><TD>18</TD><TD>71</TD><TD>57</TD><TD>42</TD><TD>69</TD><TD>14</TD><TD>307</TD><TD>271</TD><TD>-36</TD><TD>-11.73</TD></TR><TR><TD>Columbus Shoes - Red - 202035</TD><TD>27</TD><TD>50</TD><TD>68</TD><TD>45</TD><TD>26</TD><TD>6</TD><TD>229</TD><TD>222</TD><TD>-7</TD><TD>-3.06</TD></TR><TR><TD>Columbus Shoes - Tab - White/Red/Black - 214618</TD><TD>33</TD><TD>145</TD><TD>86</TD><TD>73</TD><TD>88</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>420</TD><TD>425</TD><TD>5</TD><TD>1.19</TD></TR><TR><TD>Columbus Shoes - Tab White Blue - 214617</TD><TD>54</TD><TD>156</TD><TD>43</TD><TD>47</TD><TD>70</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>372</TD><TD>370</TD><TD>-2</TD><TD>-0.54</TD></TR><TR><TD>Lotto Magic Shoes - 129726</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>4</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>8</TD><TD>1</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>13</TD><TD>13</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0.00</TD></TR><TR><TH>Grand Total</TH><TH>1369</TH><TH>2203</TH><TH>2899</TH><TH>4969</TH><TH>3229</TH><TH>802</TH><TH>14374</TH><TH>15471</TH><TH>1097</TH><TH>7.63</TH></TR></TABLE>
<br><br>Small Shoes Bulk Inventory Report <br><br>
<TABLE BORDER=1><TR><TH>Shoes</TH><TH>size 4</TH><TH>size 5</TH><TH>size 6</TH><TH>size 7</TH><TH>LastDay_Total</TH><TH>Today_Total</TH><TH>Quantity Change</TH><TH>% Change</TH></TR><TR><TD>Lotto Diva Women White Pink - 203979</TD><TD>581</TD><TD>1214</TD><TD>1067</TD><TD>475</TD><TD>3341</TD><TD>3337</TD><TD>-4</TD><TD>-0.12</TD></TR><TR><TH>Grand Total</TH><TH>581</TH><TH>1214</TH><TH>1067</TH><TH>475</TH><TH>3341</TH><TH>3337</TH><TH>-4</TH><TH>-0.12</TH></TR></TABLE>
<br><br>Apparel Bulk Inventory Report<br><br>
<TABLE BORDER=1><TR><TH>Apparel</TH><TH>Size - S</TH><TH>Size - M</TH><TH>Size - L</TH><TH>Size - XL</TH><TH>Size - XXL</TH><TH>LastDay_Total</TH><TH>Today_Total</TH><TH>Quantity Change</TH><TH>% Change</TH></TR><TR><TD>Lotto Tracksuit - 199346</TD><TD>895</TD><TD>2765</TD><TD>2763</TD><TD>1646</TD><TD>778</TD><TD>8849</TD><TD>8847</TD><TD>-2</TD><TD>-0.02</TD></TR><TR><TD>Rocio Black Bomber Jacket - 201734</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>77</TD><TD>268</TD><TD>216</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>562</TD><TD>561</TD><TD>-1</TD><TD>-0.18</TD></TR><TR><TD>Rocio Black Full Sleeve Jacket with Fur Lining - 202674</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>32</TD><TD>3</TD><TD>30</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>65</TD><TD>65</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0.00</TD></TR><TR><TD>Rocio Blue Bomber Jacket - 201735</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>117</TD><TD>324</TD><TD>313</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>754</TD><TD>754</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0.00</TD></TR><TR><TD>Rocio Mens Black Tracksuit with Blue Piping - 199529</TD><TD>426</TD><TD>1301</TD><TD>1300</TD><TD>683</TD><TD>350</TD><TD>4060</TD><TD>4060</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0.00</TD></TR><TR><TD>Rocio Mens Black Tracksuit with Red Piping - 199530</TD><TD>458</TD><TD>1226</TD><TD>1330</TD><TD>739</TD><TD>332</TD><TD>4085</TD><TD>4085</TD><TD>0</TD><TD>0.00</TD></TR><TR><TH>Grand Total</TH><TH>1779</TH><TH>5518</TH><TH>5988</TH><TH>3627</TH><TH>1460</TH><TH>18375</TH><TH>18372</TH><TH>-3</TH><TH>-0.02</TH></TR></TABLE>
```